# Inkscape: Delete an anchor & maintain the handles of connected anchors

Tags: vector, inkscape

When I do any kind of point editing with Inkscape, I will have an object (A) and delete one of the points hoping to get C, but instead I get B. I understand why this happens, it's so curves can be made more optimal, but very often I don't want my handle types to change. It is tedious enough making sure points are no-handles corners without Inkscape continually messing them up. Is there a different way I can remove anchor points that will retain the handles of its connected anchors?

[image: Three squares labeled as A, B, and C. A is plain. B has had one of its points removed and is now rounded at that corner. C shows a right triangle, the expected result from deleting a point.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

File > Inkscape Preferences
Then go to Tools > Node
Under Editing Preferences uncheck "Deleting nodes preserves shape"

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I just found [this very extensive list of hotkeys](http://inkscape.org/doc/keys046.html).

<kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Del</kbd> : delete selected node(s)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> : delete without preserving shape

Toggling the checkbox in eazimmerman's answer reverses these commands.