# Remove side symmetrically in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I wish to draw a rectangle with no fill, but only a stroke. I would like to erase a certain portion of one side, going out from the middle. I have attached a picture of what I would like to obtain at the end:

[image]

I know how to make the box in Inkscape, but I haven't figured out how to remove the part in the middle such that it looks symmetric. Does anyone know if it is possible to achieve this latter feature in Inkscape?

Answer (score 3):

These are the steps to create a box with a symmetrical opening in Inkscape:

### Cut out method

1. **Draw two boxes**, one for the resulting end box, another for defining the opening.

   [image]
2. **Select both objects** and choose *Object - Align and Distribute...* to align to the *Center on vertical axis* (choose another axis for opening on the sides),  relative to *"Biggest object"*:

   [image]
3. **Cut out** the small object from the big object with *Path - Difference*.
4. Enter *Edit path nodes* mode to **select four inner nodes**:

   [image]
5. **Delete the segment** between these nodes (make sure you had **not** set the node edit mode to [preserve shape](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21634/inkscape-delete-an-anchor-maintain-the-handles-of-connected-anchors)):

   [image]

   [image]

### Working with nodes

Another approach is working with nodes. This will not let you define a fixed width of the object in the way a second box allows but it is also fit to create a symmetrical opening.

1. Create close box.
2. Select *Path - Combine* to break nodes.
3. Select two nodes in *Edit node* mode.
4. *Insert new node* two (or more) times.

   [image]
5. Select *Object - Align and distribute*.
6. Select all nodes on base line.
7. Choose *Distribute nodes horizontally* for symmetry.

   [image]
8. Select nodes between opening.
9. *Delete segment* between two selected nodes.

   [image]